# Merging two items into one inside a List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` with the name **data** with this items:
{ A101, Plans, A102, Elev/Sec, A103, Unnamed }

```
foreach (string item in data)
{
    data1.Add(item + item);
}
```

I wanted the output to be like this:

- **A101 Plans**
- **A102 Eleve/Sec**
- **A103 Unnamed**

But the output is:

- **A101 A101**
- **Plans Plans**
- **A102 A102**
- **Eleve/Sec Eleve/Sec**
- **A103 A103**
- **Unnamed Unnamed**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, Based on the limited and poor specification given it looks like you need e.g. `return list[0]+" "+list[1];` Please improve the question if that isn't correct (I suspect what you actually want is a list where every even numbered item is combined with the next one in sequence)

Comment: Explain your logic. If you can explain it in English, you can write it in code. Do you mean that you want a method that accepts a string array, and returns an array with the first two elements of the input array combined (concatenated), followed by the remainder of the array?

Comment: So you want to concatenate the first two items of a list, separated by a space? Of course, this is possible. Like `string.Join(" ", list.Take(2))` or `list[0] + " " + list[1]`?

Comment: But is it possible to do in a general way? Like,  making a for and int **i** being the index would merge all items into pairs?

Comment: Uhm, what i want to do is merge two items into one, like the **A101 Plans, A102 Elev/Sec, A103 Unnamed**

Comment: Welcome. It's possible, can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: @KlausGütter the way you said seems good. But i would like to make it for all items in the list. i updated the question, i think its easier to understand now! Sorry for making bad questions.

Comment: And what does that code do? Have you considered debugging it to see what it does, and incrementing `i` by a larger number than 1?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yah, doesn't do nothing. That's why i would like to know if there's a way to do that.

Comment: @CodeCaster i updated the question, i think its more clear now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to do with a foreach; you'd have to remember the previous element and put the combination into a list when the memory is not blank, then blank the memory

It's easier with a straight `for` that goes in jumps of two

```
for(int i=0; i < list.Length; i+=2){
  Console.WriteLine(list[i] + " " + list[i+1]);
}
```

With a foreach it's like:

```
string x = null;
foreach(var item in list){
  if(x == null){
    x = item;
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine(x + " " + item);
    x = null;
  }
}
```

`x` flipflops between being null and something. When it is null, the item is remembered, when it is something the output is the "previous item i.e. x plus the current item"